# Is there a way to wrap text in a table cell in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I only see wrapping option for `box` object.

I thought of manually adding line breaks, but there seems to be no way of getting the chart width (only in term of bar time with `chart.left_visible_bar_time`/`chart.right_visible_bar_time`).